# Prevent calling getData of cummunity connector when filter data

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table with data that is retrieved from API via community connector. Also I have a fixed list control filled with data from some field of the same community connector that is used as a filter for the table. Every time I select an item from the control a new call of getDate is happen. Is there any trick to prevent to make these extra calls of getData?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [Cache Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache) to prevent extra calls to your API.

```
function getCampaign(campaign_id) {
  
  var endpoint = DOMAIN + GET_CAMPAIGN_ENDPOINT;
  
  // Make a POST request with form data.
  var formData = {
    'campaign_id': campaign_id,
    'with_statistics': true
  };   
  

  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var cacheKey = generateCacheKey(endpoint, formData); // generate key for the request
  var json = cache.get(cacheKey);
  if (json != null) {
    console.log('from cache');
    return JSON.parse(json);
  }
 
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, options);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  
  cache.put(cacheKey, json, 1500); // cache for 25 minutes
  console.log('from api');
  
  return JSON.parse(json);
}

function generateCacheKey(endpoint, formData){
  var s = endpoint + JSON.stringify(formData);
  return Utilities.base64Encode(s);
}
```

Comment: Sure I can implement caching and I do. But what for the data studio makes these extra calls when all the data is already in the report?

Comment: Finally I found the explanation https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/filters